# Inserting multiple rows in SQlite using a trigger

Tags: sqlite, database-trigger

I'm using SQlite, and I've **table1**:

```
Count  | Fruit | Variety
------ |------ |--------
     2 | Pear  | Nashi
     3 | Plum  | Garnet
```

Based on the information in table1, I'd like to produce **table2** in the most optimal way using a query:

```
Count  | Fruit | Variety
------ |------ |--------
     1 | Pear  | Nashi
     1 | Pear  | Nashi
     1 | Plum  | Garnet
     1 | Plum  | Garnet
     1 | Plum  | Garnet
```

Options that I looked into:

1. User defined function - not possible as I can't update the binary now. Otherwise, this would have been possible as I could create the second table as well in C++ when I do the first.
2. Briefly looked at using triggers, assuming I could allow the user to just insert a record like `(2, pear, Nashi)` into the table2, and use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger which will insert the appropriate number of records based on the count number. However, it looks like I can't use an INSTEAD OF trigger on a table.
3. Researched to see if I could find a way to run a loop in sqlite, but it looks like my chances are bleak.

There's probably a much simpler solution that I'm not aware of. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if a trigger would work, because the table you want to modify is the one which set off the trigger.  But you should be able to handle this from your app code (e.g. Android, Python, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My application is written in C++, and runs on the desktop, which cannot be modified before the next release. I'm happy to be corrected, but I'm fairly confident that a BEFORE or AFTER trigger could be setup to alter the same table for which the trigger was fired.

Comment: This would require a CTE, which is not allowed inside a trigger. Would it be possible to add another column to `table2`?

Comment: @CL. Thank you for your comment. I understand it's not possible to do this with a trigger. Would you know if I could be achieved with a query?
Yes, I am happy to modify the table2, including adding another column to it if that would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with recursive triggers and an additional column in `table2` (`RCount`) to count how many remaining triggers must be run:

```
PRAGMA recursive_triggers = ON;  -- must be executed in every connection

CREATE TRIGGER tr1
AFTER INSERT ON table1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table2(Count, Fruit, Variety, RCount)
    VALUES (1, NEW.Fruit, NEW.Variety, NEW.Count);
END;

CREATE TRIGGER tt2
AFTER INSERT ON table2
WHEN NEW.RCount > 1
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO table2(Count, Fruit, Variety, RCount)
    VALUES (1, NEW.Fruit, NEW.Variety, NEW.RCount - 1);
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I created these two triggers, and then attempted to insert a record into table1. This action resulted in the error: Error while executing SQL query: too many levels of trigger recursion

Comment: So are you using numbers larger than 1000?

Comment: And what was its count value?

Comment: The count value was 2.

Comment: Works for me. You didn't forget the `- 1`? Show your exact code.

Comment: Sorry, I had made a mistake. Your solution works perfectly, and thank you very much for helping me with this. :-)